# How to collapse columns into one using CSSGrid?

Tags: css, css-grid

The best way I can describe this is via picture, since I am unable to do this using CSSGrid. I am starting with 3 columns, each column has `n` rows. Using CSSGrid, how can I collapse these columns into one column so that all of the members of the first column are above (see second image) the members of the next column?

Codepen to illustrate the problem: https://codepen.io/robbyjm0/pen/dydjVYa

**Starting Point: 3 columns**
[image: Starting point]
**Desired outcome**
[image: Desired merge of columns]

Comment: Might need JavaScript, although you could look into setting `order` based on `nth-child` selectors. If you provide some sample code I'll have a go at it

Comment: Media queries? But an attempt would be appreciated.

Comment: I updated my question to include a link to codepen illustrating the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Uhm the way I see the structure of this is that you have 3 columns:

```
<div class='container'>
  <div class='column'>
    <div class='column__row'>
    </div>
    <div class='column__row'>
    </div>
    ....
  </div>
  <div class='column'>
    <div class='column__row'>
    </div>
    <div class='column__row'>
    </div>
    ....
  </div>
  <div class='column'>
    <div class='column__row'>
    </div>
    <div class='column__row'>
    </div>
    ....
  </div>
</div>
```

Each column can either be a grid or a flex-box (I would personally go with flex since they are just a bunch of rows)

```
.column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

And to to make them display as 3 equal size columns next to each other:

```
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}
```

To make them appear as 1 column stacking on 1 on top another:

```
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}
```

If you don't have control over the order of the html elements, you can give each column a unique id and use [grid-template-area](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_grid-template-areas.asp)